# Snowflake joins performance improvement

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-view

I need to create a view on top of a table which contains 1300+ columns. New data will be loaded to table every quarter(Rows in millions). While creating view I need to join other table with the base table. and i also needed to add a recent row indicator in view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW VIEW_NAME AS
SELECT lkp_tbl.col1,base_tbl.col1,base_tbl.col2,base_tbl.col3,........,
base_tbl.col1334, 1 as Is_Latest_Quarter 
FROM base_tbl full outer JOIN lkp_tbl
on base_tbl.CUST_ID = lkp_tbl.CUST_ID 
where snapshot_dt=(select max(snapshot_dt) from base_tbl)


union all


SELECT lkp_tbl.col1,base_tbl.col1,base_tbl.col2,base_tbl.col3,........,
base_tbl.col1334,0 as Is_Latest_Quarter 
FROM base_tbl full outer JOIN lkp_tbl 
on base_tbl.CUST_ID = lkp_tbl.CUST_ID 
where snapshot_dt!=(select max(snapshot_dt) from base_tbl);
```

After creating this view the performance of the query is too slow even if we are querying 100 rows. Is there a way in which we can create view in more efficient way. If not how can i increase performance?

Comment: Is your base table clustered by anything?  Might want to look at whether your pruning on snapshot_dt is any good and maybe try clustering it.  Also, what is the performance difference if the view isn't secure?

Comment: @MikeWalton Yes the table are clustered on run_id. we might have multiple run_id for same snapshot date.

Comment: But that seems to be a completely different query from what you originally wrote? The table names are different, the column names are different, there are additional columns involved...

Comment: sorry @NickW I just created a query that follows the structure of my original query. I have updated the sample query to follow old table names.

`CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW VIEW_NAME AS
select lkp_tbl.col1,base_tbl.* from lkp_tbl 
right join  (SELECT t.col1,t.col2,t.col3,t.col4,t.col5,...........,t.col1334,  
 case when snapshot_dt!=(select max(snapshot_dt) from base_tbl) then 0 
 else 1  
end as current_row_ind FROM base_tbl_name t)  base_tbl on base_tbl.ALT_CUST_ID = lkp_tbl.ALT_CUST_ID;`

Comment: No probs. Anyway, I've updated my previous answer with a couple of SQL options that should help you achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use one SELECT statement and use a CASE statement to calculate Is_Latest_Quarter

**UPDATED WITH (ALMOST) ACTUAL SQL**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW VIEW_NAME AS
SELECT {list of columns you want to include}
,CASE WHEN snapshot_dt=(select max(snapshot_dt) from base_tbl) THEN 1 
 ELSE 0 END as Is_Latest_Quarter
FROM base_tbl 
full outer JOIN lkp_tbl on base_tbl.CUST_ID = lkp_tbl.CUST_ID
```

Alternatively, if Snowflake doesn't like that in-line subquery, your could use a CTE something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW VIEW_NAME AS
    WITH MAX_DATE AS (SELECT MAX(Ssnapshot_dt) AS max_snapshot_dt FROM base_tbl),
    SELECT {list of columns you want to include}
    ,CASE WHEN max_date.max_snapshot_dt is not null  THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 END as Is_Latest_Quarter
    FROM base_tbl 
    full outer JOIN lkp_tbl on base_tbl.CUST_ID = lkp_tbl.CUST_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MAX_DATE ON base_tbl.snapshot_dt = max_date.max_snapshot_dt
```

Comment: I have modified my create view statement to 



`create or replace view view_name  as
select ref.Profile_KEY,base.* from reference_table_name ref right join 
(SELECT t.col1,t.col2,t.col3,t.col4,t.col5,...........,t.col1330,t.snapshot_dt,t.RUN_ID,

case
when snapshot_dt!=(select max(snapshot_dt) from base_table_name) then 0
else 1

end as current_row_ind FROM base_table_name t)  base
on base.ALT_CUST_ID = ref.ALT_CUST_ID;`



Can I improve my SQL statement further?